# What is going on with the formatting of the capital W's?

Tags: support, mathjax

The capital W's seem to be a of a completely different font sometimes. I can't help but notice them and how different they are. Is there something buggy going on? If you look at my capital W's in the editing field of the title of my question, you will see that they are different.

Comment: $$W\ \bf W\ \sf W\ \rm W$$

Comment: Yeah, but all I'm typing is shift+w and it creates a strange capital W. (This might be a terribly silly question). But really, look at the W's in my comment. What's up with that?

Comment: Your W's look fine to me. Your computer may have some issues with its font configuration. It's hard to say more unless you post a screenshot, unless robjohn's answer has satisfied you (though I see no math in your question or comment).

Comment: The W's in the edit field *do* look weird. They look as if they belong to a totally different font...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font for the math text is chosen by MathJax. It is different than what the browser chooses for its text. The difference between the MathJax characters is caused by the font modifiers specified. The first is italic (with serifs), the second is bold (with serifs), the third is plain (without serifs), the fourth is plain (with serifs).
$$
W\ \bf W\ \sf W\ \rm W
$$

Comment: many thanks~ for your answer

Comment: Fourth is Roman, not plain. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I meant plain as in "not bold". Roman means upright, but can apply to serif, sans serif, bold, and not bold. Italic is skewed, usually with serif, and can be bold or not. Oblique is generally used for sans serif skewed fonts, bold or not.